# Is it possible to download files created on Stypi and in the same format?

Tags: collaboration, group-project

I'm looking for a tool for programming in real time with my partners and [Stypi](https://code.stypi.com) seems very nice but the download option would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to download your code on Stypi, I have looked for a while on Google. You can always create a new file on your computer and copy the code down into that file though.